# Lower bounds for linear forms of logarithms (a la Baker)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lower-bounds

Let $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $a$ be three fixed complex algebraic
numbers.

For a given integer $n$, write
$\Theta(n) = \arg(a \lambda_1^n + \lambda_2^n)$.

Assuming $\Theta(n)$ is not zero, I am looking for 'good' lower bounds on
$|\Theta(n)|$. By 'good' I mean that if $|\Theta(n)| > B(n)$,
then $1/B(n)$ should asymptotically grow slower that any exponential in $n$.

Is there a way to use one of Baker's theorems (which provide effective
lower bounds on linear combinations of logs of algebraic numbers) to achieve
this?

For example, writing instead $\Gamma(n) = \arg(a \lambda_1^n \lambda_2^n)$
(say), one can get *polynomial* bounds on $|\Gamma(n)|$: noting that
$\displaystyle{\Gamma(n) = \log\left(\frac{a \lambda_1^n \lambda_2^n}
{|a \lambda_1^n \lambda_2^n|}\right) =
\log a + n \log \lambda_1 + n \log \lambda_2 - \log |a| -
n \log |\lambda_1| - n \log |\lambda_2|}$
we can apply e.g. Baker-Wustholz (1993) to the above linear form
and get a lower bound $|\Gamma(n)| > C(n)$ (assuming that $|\Gamma(n)|$ is non-zero)
such that $1/C(n)$ is in fact bounded by a fixed polynomial in $n$.

The problem in getting a similar lower bound for $|\Theta(n)|$ is that, even though
$\Theta(n)$ can be written as a linear combination of logs of algebraic
numbers of constant degree, as for $\Gamma(n)$, the *height* of the
algebraic number $a \lambda_1^n + \lambda_2^n$ is potentially exponential in
$n$, and it does not seem that taking logs will help here.

The critical case is of course when $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ have the
same magnitude. In fact, I would be happy for an approach with even very
simple values of $a$, such as $a = 2$.